# Atom not recognizing webdriver

Tags: python

So I am trying to run a script that I made in PyCharm in Atom. In the project folder, the script exists along with a webdriver.

When writing this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I get this

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I only get this on Atom. It works perfectly fine in Pycharm and Sublime Text 3.

Is there a setting in Atom I need to enable or something?

Answer (score 0):

Download chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and then use this:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chromedriver/executable")`

Comment: That's exactly what I did before, still didn't work. I'll probably add that to my main question.